# How to safely write TensorFlow model if I'm using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing module for training multiple models in parallel. Each model is rather small (10000 parameters). I create several processes and each process successively trains several models. After the training process of the model is completed, I'm saving the model.
It looks like that:

```
try:                       
    models[i].save(save_path)                
except Exception as E:                
    print('SAVING ERROR')
    print(E)
```

I've never seen exception in the console output, but when I'm trying to load model the model doesn't exist. The stange thing is that such issue is not persistent: sometimes there is no problems at all.
Also I tried to return multiprocessing results but did'nt managed to overcome pickle issues.

Comment: why not save the model from inside the child processes themselves? That way you won't have to pickle them at all.

Comment: Yes, I'm saving model from the child process just after training done.

Answer (score 0):

When a mixture of Keras models need to be trained , it is better to have all of the models to be in the same process instead of different processes controlling different models.

Hence instead of doing something like this ,

```
import keras

def training_function(...):
    ...
```

It is better to do this :

```
def training_function(...):
    import keras
    ...
```

Please refer to this code [illustration](https://github.com/yuanyuanli85/Keras-Multiple-Process-Prediction) to get the idea of it.

With that being said creating workers in separate processes would prevent choking of memory as the memory gets freed once the process is completed.

```
def _training_worker(train_params):
    import keras
    model = obtain_model(train_params)
    model.fit(train_params)
    send_message_to_main_process(...)

def train_new_model(train_params):
    training_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=_training_worker, args = train_params)
    training_process.start()
    get_message_from_training_process(...)
    training_process.join()
```